# I am getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module" while trying to import firebase in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I made the react app using create-react-app and installed  firebase : 8.2.3, but while importing firebase in App.js I am getting error "Cannot use import statement outside a module" and my app doesn't run.
here are my package.json configuration:

{
"name": "sample-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^8.2.3",
"gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-lazyload": "^3.1.0",
"react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "0.9.x",
"react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
"zustand": "^3.1.4"
},

"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
}

Comment: show us your import statement

Comment: Can you show us what's your folder structure looks like? For importing any module inside a CRA app, you'd just need to `import firebase from "firebase/app"` and that should work just fine